# ブラウザからDNS逆引きを実行する方法はありますか?

Tags: javascript, dns

ブラウザから逆引きを行いたいのですが何か方法はありますか?

理想としては`JavaScript`から直接Digコマンドのようなものが打てればよいのですが、`JavaScript`にそのような関数は存在するのでしょか。

それ以外で思いつくのはサーバー側で`dig`コマンドで取得した情報を`ajax`でやりとりする方法なのですが、複数人が同時に使用するとなると同一のIPから大量に逆引きを仕掛ける事になるので、避けたいです。
複数のサーバーを用意するほどでもないですし。。。
何か良い方法があれば教えて下さい。

Comment: どんなアプリケーションに使おうとしているのでしょうか面白そうですね。もしブラウザや環境が限定できるのならその由を書き加えると、ブラウザ・環境依存の方法ながら可能になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

[英語版のStackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435678/whois-with-javascript)にJavaScriptから利用できる whois Web サービスが紹介されていました。
[逆引き](https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/reverse-ip-api.php)も出来るようですが、有償のものしかなさそうです。

Answer (score 1):

これでできそうじゃない？
http://www.statdns.com/api/

特に、ページの下の方にある「Get reverse (PTR) record from IPv4 addresses」か「Get reverse (PTR) record from IPv6 addresses」のURL形式でAjaxリクエストを出すと無料で何回もJSONのリスポンスがいただけるようです。

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptにはAPIが存在しないので、サーバー側でリクエストする必要があります。

サーバー側でBINDなどのDNSキャッシュサーバを導入すれば、外部DNSサーバーへのリクエストをなるべく減らすことができます。